# ¿Por qué la asincronía no funciona en estos casos?

Tags: c#, mvc, async-await

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web en C# Framework 4.5 MVC.

En este caso en concreto, un controlador debe devolver a la vista un ViewModel, cuyos datos se obtiene de forma asíncrona. Actualmente la asincronía está funcionando correctamente con este código, ejecutando las tareas `GetData1Async()` y `GetData2Async()` en paralelo:

```
[HttpGet]   
public async Task<ActionResult> _PartialViewAsync1() {

    var Repository1 = new Repository1();
    var Repository2 = new Repository2();

    var Data1 = Repository1.GetData1Async();
    var Data2 = Repository2.GetData2Async();

    ViewModel Vm = new ViewModel
    {

        VmData1 = await Data1,
        VmData2 = await Data2

    };

    return PartialView("_PartiaViewAsync1", Vm);

}
```

Sin embargo, si asigno directamente los valores a las propiedades del ViewModel, los datos se devuelven correctamente a la vista, pero las tareas se ejecutan una detrás de otra, es decir, la asincronía no funciona:

```
[HttpGet]   
public async Task<ActionResult> _PartialViewAsync1() {

    var Repository1 = new Repository1();
    var Repository2 = new Repository2();

    ViewModel Vm = new ViewModel
    {

        VmData1 = await Repository1.GetData1Async(),
        VmData2 = await Repository2.GetData2Async()

    };

    return PartialView("_PartiaViewAsync1", Vm);

}
```

¿Alguien sabría explicar por qué esto es así? Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al usar `await`, en términos simples, el código asíncrono se convierte en síncrono ya que se espera a que finalice para continuar con la ejecución del programa.

En el caso:

```
    VmData1 = await Repository1.GetData1Async(),
    VmData2 = await Repository2.GetData2Async()
```

El primer `await` espera a que termine la llamada a `GetData1Async()`, cuando finaliza pasa al siguiente `await`.

En el otro caso:

```
    var Data1 = Repository1.GetData1Async();
    var Data2 = Repository2.GetData2Async();
```

Como no se usa `await`, se llama al método `GetData1Async()`, este empieza ejecutarse de forma asíncrona y luego el programa continúa con la llamada a `GetData2Async()`. En ese punto los dos códigos asíncronos ya se están ejecutando.

Cuando se llega a:

```
    VmData1 = await Data1,
    VmData2 = await Data2
```

El `await` funciona igual, espera que a que `Data1` tenga su valor, y luego pasa al siguiente `await`, con la diferencia que mientras se espera que `Data1` tenga valor, el resultado de `Data2` ya se está procesando también.